# Sharepoint 2007 search not work for specific words "lånelöfte"

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We are  using SharePoint 2007 default search, somehow it is not working for specific words such as " lånelöfte, Larmpaket, Vattenfelsbrytare". But If search for words such as "lanelöfte", "länelöfte" then it search properly and also displays result for word "lånelöfte".

We added this words in noise file, also set diacritic sensitive to true.